How do I make an array threadsafe in Java?
I am pretty new to multithreading and want to understand it better. I want to now how to make an array threadsafe in Java? Meaning I have several threads accessing and changing the data in the array and I want to prevent one thread from changing the data, while the other thread is reading it.
My approach was the following:
I have a Data class containing an array and two methods updateData(Integer[] data) and getUpdate() for accessing and manipulating the array.
public class  Data <T extends Comparable> {
    private T[] data;

    public T[] getUpdate() {
        synchronized (this) {
            return data.clone();
        }
    }

    public void updateData(T[] data) {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.data = data.clone();
        }
    }
}

This data object is now used in two different threads, the main thread which updates the data and the swing EDT thread which reads the data and uses it.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Data<Integer> data = new Data<>();
    data.updateData(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10});


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        ColumnVisualizer visualizer = new ColumnVisualizer();

        new Timer(100, e -> {
            visualizer.setData(data.getUpdate());
        }).start();
    });
    
    while(condition) {
        data.updateData(createNewData());

    }
}

As I understand it if I access the array only through the updateData() and getUpdate() methods, which I made threadsafe with the synchronized keyword, the data itself is threadsafe. Since if a thread calls the getUpdate() method it sets a lock on the Data instance and when another thread wants to call updateData() it can not access the part where the old array is replaced with the new one, until the Data instance is not longer looked on.
Have I understand it correctly and is this a convenient approach to make the array threadsafe in Java?

This has nothing to do with making an array thread-safe (which effectively is not possible). The code shown is about replacing an object (which happens to be an array) in a thread-safe manner. The code shown is thread-safe, and read operation on that array will be thread-safe, provided it isn't modified (as in individual entries of the array receiving a new value) by other threads after updateData was called, and that is because arrays themselves are not thread-safe, and cannot be made intrinsically thread-safe (operations always require some form of mutual exclusion to be thread-safe).

Immutable Data-Structures are always threadsafe.

I deleted my answer. I said, "not thread safe," because it seemed to me that the class allows an unsafe way of using it. But is there any reasonable thing you could have done to prevent the unsafe use? Suddenly, I'm not so sure. Nothing is completely fool proof. They're always inventing better fools.

Your understanding is correct. The Data instance will be blocked until the synchronized block is finished in either one of the methods (getUpdate/updateData).
Though, based on your code I have some observations, that might be useful for you.
Let's assume that at timestamp time1, a thread, let's call it th1, comes and and calls getUpdate and fetches a clone of the data. Assuming that one millisecond later (or sooner) another thread, let's call I th2, gets the cloned data from the same method getUpdate. At this point both th1 and th2 have the same entries in data table.
Assuming that after 4 milliseconds process of th1 updates the data by using the updateData and after 1 millisecond, process th2 calls the same method.
Let's see what happened with this 2 processes: Right after the call of of updateData of th2, the data table will have whatever th2 placed there, having completely ignored what the th1 placed there 1 milisecond ago (process th1 is like never happened).
Is this what you want ? I'm not saying it is wrong, I'm just saying it is what will happen if 2 process will use the table at pretty much the same time (with 1ms or less difference).
If what you want is at the end of th2 the data table to contain information of both th1 and th2 you will probably need different approach.
Eg. lock the table for a process, or use methods class Data to add/remove entries in the table without giving the whole table to a process to update it....

Thank you for your answer! About your question, I did change the code to make it clear and to underline my question with it. The code does not necessarily make sense, as I left out some logic inside the synchronized blocks.

The Java Language Specification writes:

Memory that can be shared between threads is called shared memory or heap memory.
All instance fields, static fields, and array elements are stored in heap memory. In this chapter, we use the term variable to refer to both fields and array elements.
Local variables (§14.4), formal method parameters (§8.4.1), and exception handler parameters (§14.20) are never shared between threads and are unaffected by the memory model.
Two accesses to (reads of or writes to) the same variable are said to be conflicting if at least one of the accesses is a write.

and then describes at length that some kind of synchronization is required between conflicting accesses in different threads.
To answer your question about the thread safety of this array, we therefore need to identify which variables may be accessed in a conflicting way in separate threads:
The first such variable is the field data which holds the reference to the array. It's easy to see that data is read and written by different threads. Therefore, some kind of synchronization action is required. Since the variable is always accessed in a synchronized block (on the same object), we know that the monitor is first unlocked and then locked between conflicting accesses, and since

an unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

we can conclude that the threads have synchronized between the conflicting accesses to this variable, allow us to rely on the write having happened before (and being visible to) the read.
Ok, what about the array elements? Are there any conflicting accesses in separate threads? We note that we actually have 3 different arrays: the original array being passed to updateData(...), the copy created within updateData(...), and the copy created within getData(). Of these, only the second is accessed by separate threads, and the accesses are conflicting, since we write the array and then read it in the other thread. However, we can apply the same reasoning as for data to conclude that a synchronization action happened between these accesses, and the access is therefore correctly synchronized.
Last, we turn our attention to the fields of the T object that have been passed from one thread to the other. We don't know how these fields are accessed, and therefore can not conclude with certainty whether the code is correctly sychronized. For instance, if the writing thread were to write to some fields of T after sharing the reference to the T object with another thread, we may have a conflicting access without synchronization, which would make the program incorrectly synchronized. However, if we know that the writing thread does not modify the T objects after sharing them with the other thread, we know (from the above reasoning) that the handover involved a synchronization action, meaning that the threads synchronized between the write and the read, and we can therefore rely on the write having happened before (and being visible to) the read.
(Incidentally, we could have applied the same reasoning to the array elements: If the array elements are only written before the reference to the array is handed over to the other thread with proper synchronization, the threads are known to have synchronized between the write and the read. That is, the following variant of your code is also correct:
public class  Data <T extends Comparable> {
    private T[] data;

    public T[] getUpdate() {
        T[] d;
        synchronized (this) {
            d = this.data;
        }
        return d.clone();
    }

    public void updateData(T[] data) {
        var copy = data.clone();
        synchronized (this) {
            this.data = copy;
        }
    }
}

but has the advantage that the copying (which may, depending on array length, take a while) will not block the other thread, making the handover more efficient.
In fact, safely sharing a reference to an object with another thread is such a common pattern that the Java API offers a class for that purpose, which would allow us to simplify your code further:
public class  Data <T extends Comparable> {
    private final AtomicReference<T[]> data;

    public T[] getUpdate() {
        return data.get().clone();
    }

    public void updateData(T[] data) {
        this.data.set(data.clone());
    }
}

or alternatively we could simply make the reference volatile, because

A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

public class  Data <T extends Comparable> {
    private volatile T[] data;

    public T[] getUpdate() {
        return data.clone();
    }

    public void updateData(T[] data) {
        this.data = data.clone();
    }
}

